# Logins take a long time

Tags: debian, password, pam

After upgrading to Debian 7.4 password authentication from any service take a long time. This is true for SSH logins, sudo'ing and authentication with dovecot (which is configured to use PAM).

I am able to reverse lookup DNS entries, this does not seem to be the problem. It feels like some authentication mechanism is running into a timeout. I have tried to enable pam_debug, but I don't see any debugging output going anywhere.

Here is an example of how long it takes to do a sudo (with a password prompt, during the time that sudo caches the password, it works instantly):

```
ceicke@h1633420:~$ time sudo who
[sudo] password for ceicke:
ceicke   pts/0        2014-08-01 09:19 (80.131.XXX.XXX)

real    0m27.976s
user    0m0.009s
sys 0m0.014s
```

Also SSHing into the box with my private key works instantly. So really the password checking process takes a long time.

I am a little lost on what else I can try, especially since the PAM module is very very silent about what it is doing.

## Update #1

Here is the output of strace: http://pastebin.com/dRvqsrcd

There are a *lot* of calls of `time(null)` which I guess gets the current Unix timestamp. Seems like something is actively checking for a timeout.

I notice two things:

1. the `time(null)` call is often preceded with an open call to `/dev/urandom`, can it be that my server is waiting to gather enough entropy?
2. there are a lot of references to `krb5` in various places. I do not use Kerberos to authenticate, can I simply take out `pam_krb5.so` from my pam configs?

I do not have a lot of experiences readying strace output, maybe you can see more?

## Update #2

Entropy is fairly low on the server, between 100 - 200.

Comment: Can you give us some output from `strace -f sudo who`, particularly around the time of the pause?

Comment: To test whether something is waiting to gather entropy that's in short supply, try pressing the Shift key several times while e.g. `who` is waiting to finish.  When I had a similar problem once before, a few keypresses provided entropy that quickly got things moving again.

Answer (score 5):

My first advice would also be trying `strace -f sudo who`. But this won't work, since strace will not trace SUID programs. You have to attach to your shell using `strace` as **root** and then call `sudo`.

In your shell type

```
$ echo $$
```

to get your shells PID. Then open another terminal and become root in that terminal. There you type

```
# strace -f -t -T -p $pid -o /tmp/sudo.strace
```

where `$pid` is the PID you got from the other terminal. Then go back to your first terminal and start

```
$ sudo who
```

After you got the output, go back to the root terminal, stop the strace process with CTRL-C and analyze /tmp/sudo.strace

**Update:**
Sorry, I forgot to mention two options to `strace`. With `-t` it prefixes each line with the time of the day and with `-T` it shows the time spent in system calls. These facilitate finding the point where it gets slow.

**Update 2:**
Given that you don't need Kerberos, disabling pam_krb5 could be an option. You can comment it out in the files in */etc/pam.d/*, usually in the files named *common-**. Kerberos needs some entropy and this could be the culprit. But nevertheless verify this assumption by running `strace` with `-t`.

And you shoud **change your password**, since it is readable in the text file you uploaded to pastebin.

Comment: Thanks for spotting the password, saw it too in the dump after uploading it.

Answer (score 1):

So, it turned out that Kerberos in combination with low entropy was causing the problem. Since I was not using Kerberos, I ran `pam-auth-update` and unselected Kerberos.